# Android get resource type of id

Tags: android, resources

I search for a way to say which resource type is behind a integer ID. For example i have the id of a drawable and another one for a color. I can load the drawable with Resource.getDrawable(id) and the color with Resource.getColor(ID) but how can i know which method is the right one for a given ID. I look for something like Resource.isColor(id)?
Has anybody a good idea. I wrote a image loader which loads images from web, filesystem and drawables but now also from hex color or color ID.

Answer (score 8):

Check out [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getResourceTypeName%28int%29) function from android Resources class. `Resources.getResourceTypeName(int resid)` (also [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getResourceName%28int%29) )

Answer (score 0):

To find the resource type the safest solution is to use the below code

```
String viewName = findViewById(resourceId).toString();
String resourcetype = viewName.substring(0,viewName.indexOf("{"));
```

The **resoucetype** then contains the full classname for the resource, eg in case of EditText, it shows

```
android.widget.EditText
```

Tried some other ideas but noted  that `getResourceTypeName` only returns 'id' as value and `getTag()` on View does not work in all conditions.